# Keystonejs: generated URL type field is not opened as a link by click

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I use Keystone JS `Types.Url` type of field to show clickable (by link) field of object in the generated admin UI:

```
Message.add({
  uId: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  title: { type: String, initial: true, required: true },
  stat: { type: Types.Url, default: '', required: false, label: 'Statistics' }
})

Message.schema.add({ status: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed })

Message.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.stat = 'link_to_config'
  next()
})

Message.defaultColumns = 'uId, stat'
Message.register()
```

Field **'stat'** is shown correctly by `<a href="">` in the generated admin UI.

Problem:

Field **'stat'** is not opened with a click, **but the link is changed** in the browser's address bar correctly or it can be opened by using `ctrl + click`

Is it a bug or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `URL` type is not meant to appear as a URL in the Admin panel. It's meant to provide validation and formatting for items to be stored as URLs; they have no function as clickable links within the Admin panel at all.

Source: http://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/url/

Comment: It's a pity, because on the page of items (not item details page) this field of item looks clickable (generated <a href> tag). But it does not work correctly.